# Is there a way to stop my pages from just flashing in and out whenever I navigate to them?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Whenever I navigate from any page to the map page, the map page will just flash up, show it for a bit and then disappear and take me back to the page where I started.

[image: This is a .gif file of to show what happens when I try to navigate to the Map Page.]

I recently fixed my prior navigation view problem with it not navigating at all. I have two different switch statements for navigating as you'll see, which might be the problem but this issue doesn't happen anywhere else.

Main Page C# code:

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void NavView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           foreach (NavigationViewItemBase item in NavView.MenuItems)
            {
                if (item is NavigationViewItem && item.Tag.ToString() == "Home")
                {
                    NavView.SelectedItem = item;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }


        private void NavView_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.IsSettingsInvoked)
            {
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
            }
            else
            {
                switch (args.InvokedItem)
                {
                    case "Home":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
                        break;

                    case "Attractions":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(AttractionsPage));
                        break;

                    case "Places to Eat":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(PlacestoEatPage));
                        break;

                    case "Map":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
                        break;

                    case "Photos":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Photos_Page));
                        break;

                    case "News":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(NewsFeedPage));
                        break;

                    case "Weather":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(WeatherPage));
                        break;


                }


            }
        }

        private void NavView_SelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.IsSettingsSelected)
            {
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
            }
            else
            {
                NavigationViewItem item = args.SelectedItem as NavigationViewItem;
                switch (item.Tag)
                {
                    case "home":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
                        break;

                    case "attractions":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(AttractionsPage));
                        break;

                    case "placestoEat":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(PlacestoEatPage));
                        break;

                    case "map":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
                        break;

                    case "photos":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Photos_Page));
                        break;

                    case "news":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(NewsFeedPage));
                        break;

                    case "weather":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(WeatherPage));
                        break;

                }
            }
        }

        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
 }
```

This is the MapPage C# code with just the navigation view code (if I need to put the rest in which is just code about markers for specific places on the map and the different map styles let me know):

```
private void NavView_ItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.IsSettingsInvoked)
            {
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
            }
            else
            {
                switch (args.InvokedItem)
                {
                    case "Home":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
                        break;

                    case "Attractions":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(AttractionsPage));
                        break;

                    case "Places to Eat":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(PlacestoEatPage));
                        break;

                    case "Map":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
                        break;

                    case "Photos":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Photos_Page));
                        break;

                    case "News":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(NewsFeedPage));
                        break;

                    case "Weather":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(WeatherPage));
                        break;
                }

            }
        }

        private void NavView_SelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.IsSettingsSelected)
            {
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
            }
            else
            {
                NavigationViewItem item = args.SelectedItem as NavigationViewItem;
                switch (item.Tag)
                {
                    case "home":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
                        break;

                    case "attractions":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(AttractionsPage));
                        break;

                    case "placestoEat":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(PlacestoEatPage));
                        break;

                    case "map":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
                        break;

                    case "photos":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Photos_Page));
                        break;

                    case "news":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(NewsFeedPage));
                        break;

                    case "weather":
                        Frame.Navigate(typeof(WeatherPage));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked out this article ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/page-transitions..

Answer (score 0):

After going through my c# code I realized that I had accidentally copied the code from the main page where it set the main page as the page to go to. I took that out and it worked itself out.

Thanks for the help!